# Problems computing the score of a pairwise list in an iterative way?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, iteration, python-itertools

Let's suppose that I have the following lists (actually they have a lot of sublists):

```
list_1 = [['Hi my name is anon'],
                 ['Hi I like #hokey']]


list_2 = [['Hi my name is anon_2'],
                 ['Hi I like #Basketball']]
```

I would like to compute the [distance](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Distance/) of all the possible pairwises with no repetetions (combinations without replacement, product?). For example:

```
distance between: ['Hi my name is anon'] and ['Hi my name is anon_2']
distance between: ['Hi my name is anon'] and ['Hi I like #Basketball']
distance between: ['Hi I like #hokey'] and ['Hi my name is anon_2']
distance between: ['Hi I like #hokey'] and ['Hi I like #Basketball']
```

And place the scores into a list like this:

```
[distance_1,distance_2,distance_3,distance_4]
```

For this I was thinking on using itertools [product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) or [combination](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). This is what I tried:

```
strings_1 = [i[0] for i in list_1]
strings_2 = [i[0] for i in list_2]

import itertools

scores_list = [dis.jaccard(i,j) for i,j in zip(itertools.combinations(strings_1, strings_2))]
```

The problem is I am getting this traceback:

```
    scores_list = [dis.jaccard(i,j) for i,j in zip(itertools.combinations(strings_1, strings_2))]
TypeError: an integer is required
```

How can I do efficientely this task and how can I compute this product-combination-like operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get the cartesian product, like this

```
[dis.jaccrd(string1, string2) for string1, string2 in product(list_1, list_2)]
```

The product will group the items, like this

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(list(product(list_1, list_2)))
[(['Hi my name is anon'], ['Hi my name is anon_2']),
 (['Hi my name is anon'], ['Hi I like #Basketball']),
 (['Hi I like #hokey'], ['Hi my name is anon_2']),
 (['Hi I like #hokey'], ['Hi I like #Basketball'])]
```

---

If you want to apply the `jaccrd` function only to the strings within the lists, then you might want to preprocess the lists, like this

```
>>> list_11 = [item for items in list_1 for item in items]
>>> list_21 = [item for items in list_2 for item in items]
>>> pprint([str1 + " " + str2 for str1, str2 in product(list_11, list_21)])
['Hi my name is anon Hi my name is anon_2',
 'Hi my name is anon Hi I like #Basketball',
 'Hi I like #hokey Hi my name is anon_2',
 'Hi I like #hokey Hi I like #Basketball']
>>> pprint([dis.jaccard(str1, str2) for str1, str2 in product(list_11, list_21)])
...
...
```

---

As suggested by Ashwini in the comments, for your case, you can directly use [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap), like this

```
>>> from itertools import product, starmap
>>> list(starmap(dis.jaccrd, product(list_11, list_21)))
```

For example,

```
>>> list_1 = ["a1", "a2", "a3"]
>>> list_2 = ["b1", "b2", "b3"]
>>> from itertools import product, starmap
>>> list(starmap(lambda x, y: x + " " + y, product(list_1, list_2)))
['a1 b1', 'a1 b2', 'a1 b3', 'a2 b1', 'a2 b2', 'a2 b3', 'a3 b1', 'a3 b2', 'a3 b3']
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!. So once I preprocess the list as you said where do I apply the `jaccard` function?

Comment: @skwoi Yup. See the last example. You can pass `str1` and `str2` to the `jaccard` function.

Comment: To completely remove Python loop apply  `itertools.starmap` on product.

Comment: Thanks for the help @AshwiniChaudhary could you provide some example?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Oh yeah. Thanks man :-) Included that in the answer now.

Comment: @skwoi I included sample code with `itertools.starmap` as well.

Comment: Thanks @thefourtheye I am checking it up!

Comment: In the last update I got this: `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
` @thefourtheye

Comment: @skwoi Did you do the preprocessing, which I have shown in the answer? Can you please show the actual code which you tried?

Comment: Thanks I got confused @thefourtheye

Comment: @thefourtheye in order to remove the commuted instances I from your excelent answer I tried this: `score_list_2 = [dis.jaccard(string1, string2) for string1, string2 in combinations(list_1, list_2)]` the problem is that I get: `TypeError: an integer is required`. How can I remove the commuted pairwises of the product operation?.

Comment: @skwoi Can you show the actual code and data with which you tried?

Answer (score 1):

`product` works, but since you just have pairs, this works as well:

```
[dis.jaccard(string1, string2) for string1 in list_1 for string2 in list_2]
```

That said, the `starmap` + `product` combination of course wins.

Comment: `product` is not an overkill, it is fast and is meant for this purpose.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary It's slower than double comprehension (at least in a test I just did), it's more code, and it's unnecessarily powerful. But I'll remove the term anyway. And you're of course right about `starmap`, where `product` then indeed is better.

Comment: Thank yo very much guys!

Comment: @StefanPochmann thanks for your help. How can I drop the replacements from your aproach?. In order to create a smaller list of scores?. For example, let's say I have: `list_1 = [["a1"], ["a2"], ["a3"]]`and
`list_2 = [["a1"], ["a2"], ["a3"]]` How can I remove the commuted instances, for example, from `['a1 a1', 'a1 a2', 'a1 a3',
 'a2 a1', 'a2 a2', 'a2 a3', 'a3 a1', 'a3 a2', 'a3 a3']` to soemthing like this: `['a1 a1', 'a1 a2', 'a1 a3', 'a2 a2', 'a2 a3', 'a3 a3']`

Comment: @skwoi In this example, the two lists are the same. Might they also differ, or are they always the same?

Comment: Ohh... sorry let's assume that `list_2` is with `bi` @StefanPochmann. Thanks for the feed

Comment: @skwoi In my solution, I'd add `if string1 <= string2` before the ending `]`.

Comment: @skwoi Also works with thefourtheye's list comprehension, of course. Just not in the `starmap` solution.